# How to solve a 2nd order non-homogeneous linear recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I have a problem in solving this equation :

$x_{n+2} + 3\ x_{n+1} + 2\ x_{n} = 5 \times 3^n $

given that $x_{0} = 0$ and $x_{1} = 1$.

I solved the homogeneous associated equation and got $v_{n} = c_{1} \times (-1)^{n} + c_{2} \times (-2)^{n}$ (where $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$ are constants). 
Could somebody explain the general method for solving second order non-homogeneous linear recurrence ?

Comment: Why is the function's name $x$? Also, what have you tried? Have you tried to input some values and see the results? Solving similar equations? If so, please add it to the question.

Comment: just changed the question and add info.

Comment: +1, exactly! Sorry I don't know how to answer. But now it's more likely you get an answer.

Comment: The 'annihilator' method will give you this question quite easily. Have a look around the Internet. (There's a similar method for DE, so include recurrence in your search to avoid confusion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you need to find a particular solution of the inhomogeneous equation, and the rhs suggest that something of the form $c(n)3^n$ should work. The simplest form of $c$ is a constant, so try that. If it works, you are golden, if not, try a linear function, etc, then add the homogeneous solution and you are good.

Answer (score 1):

I have just found the solution. This is not general method, but some piece of heuristics. May be it somehow will help you to find some solutions in simple cases.
I use method of undetermined coeficients. I guess, that should be $$x_n=c3^n+d(-1)^n,$$ for some real constants $c,d$. Now, calculation of $c,d$ is very simple. We have also 
$$x_{n+1}=3c3^n-d(-1)^n$$
$$x_{n+2}=9c3^n+d(-1)^n,$$
so:
$$x_{n+2}+3x_{n+1}+2x_n=9c3^n+d(-1)^n+ 9c3^n-3d(-1)^n+2c3^n+2d(-1)^n=20c3^{n}$$
From the recurrence must be: $$20c3^{n}=5.3^n,$$ so: $c=\frac{1}{4}$.
Now we know, that $$\frac{3^n}{4}+d(-1)^n$$ satisfies your recurrence. And because $x_0=0$, we must have $d=-\frac14$.
Therefore we have following result:
$$x_n=\frac{3^n}{4}-\frac{(-1)^n}4.$$

Comment: How can you 'guess' that the $ c_{2} (-2)^{n}$ isn't part of the general solution? I have the same answer but I first need to resolve some equations before knowing that $c_{2} = 0$.

Comment: It's just my heuristic. First I was trying shapes $P(n).3^n$, where $P(n)$ is polynomial. Because in that case all terms $x_n,x_{n+1},x_{n+2}$ are something times $3^n$, so there is a chance get in result your recurrence. First try didn't work. But later I was trying shapes $P(n).3^n+Q(n)(-1)^n$ and I was successful. But, you can also transform your recurrence to a linear with constants. But I forgot details of standard procedure, how to solve that kind of recurences.

Answer (score 0):

Use generating functions directly. Define $G(z) = \sum_{n \ge 0} x_n z^n$, multiply by $z^n$ and sum over $n \ge 0$, recognize a few sums:
$$
\frac{G(z) - x_0 - x_1 z}{z^2} + 3 \frac{G(z) - x_0}{z} + 2 G(z)
  = 5 \frac{1}{1 - 3 z}
$$
As partial fractions:
$$
A(z) = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 3 z} - \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 + z}
$$
Everything in sight is just geometric series;
$$
a_n
  = \frac{3^n - (-1)^n}{4}
$$